# ARM cross compiler - arm-linux-gnueabihf error. liblto_plugin.so not found

Tags: shared-library, arm, cross-compilation

I am trying to make a linux kernel - 4.15.17.  It is a project I have inherited, and it appears to use the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` compiler.  Below is the output from the make process:

```
ndu@ndu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/linux-4.15.17$ make
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  VDSO    arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so.raw
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
compilation terminated.
arch/arm/vdso/Makefile:38: recipe for target 'arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so.raw' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/vdso/vdso.so.raw] Error 1
Makefile:1033: recipe for target 'arch/arm/vdso' failed
make: *** [arch/arm/vdso] Error 2
```

I have found the file, but for some reason it can't be found during the make process:

```
usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/liblto_plugin.so
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you help us to understand how this is an Ubuntu-specific question?  Are you familiar with the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), which is an ARM-focused community?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a symbolic link to /lib

```
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/liblto_plugin.so /lib/liblto_plugin.so
```

probably looking there for it.